# Mostrar texto actualizado con SelectableText

Tags: flutter

Estoy intentando realizar los siguiente en una app flutter:
Que al seleccionar un texto, este pueda ser editado y reemplace al texto original.
Ya hice la implementacion mediante `SelectableText` y el menú mediante `contextMenuBuilder`, al cual le agregué un boton personalizado (Lo llamé "Cambiar a Rojo", porque lo que intento lograr es que el texto seleccionado se pinte de color rojo), con un `setState` al momento de clikear `onPresed`.
Me selecciona correctamente el texto, me aparece el menú con el botón Cambiar a Rojo, pero al clikear no cambia de color el texto.

Este es el código de mi widget.

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_import
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'list_view_predicas_model.dart';
export 'list_view_predicas_model.dart';

class ListViewPredicasWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListViewPredicasWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListViewPredicasWidgetState createState() => _ListViewPredicasWidgetState();
}

class _ListViewPredicasWidgetState extends State<ListViewPredicasWidget> {
  late ListViewPredicasModel _model;
    
  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback callback) {
    super.setState(callback);
    _model.onUpdate();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => ListViewPredicasModel());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.maybeDispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<FFAppState>();    

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0),
      child: StreamBuilder<List<PredicasRecord>>(
        stream: queryPredicasRecord(
          queryBuilder: (predicasRecord) =>
              predicasRecord.orderBy('orden_predica'),
        ),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 50.0,
                height: 50.0,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primary,
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
          List<PredicasRecord> listViewPredicasRecordList = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: listViewPredicasRecordList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, listViewIndex) {
              final listViewPredicasRecord =
                  listViewPredicasRecordList[listViewIndex];
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0),
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).gray200,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).gray600,
                      width: 1.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                            child: SelectionArea(
                                child: Text(
                              listViewPredicasRecord.temaPredica!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .bodyMedium
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
                                    color:
                                        FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).black600,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    useGoogleFonts: false,
                                  ),
                            )),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                            child: SelectionArea(
                                child: Text(
                              listViewPredicasRecord.fechaPredica!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .bodyMedium
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
                                    color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).gray600,
                                    fontSize: 14.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                                    useGoogleFonts: false,
                                  ),
                            )),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
                            child: SelectableText(
                              listViewPredicasRecord.textoPredica!,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .bodyMedium
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
                                    color:
                                        FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).black600,
                                    letterSpacing: 2.0,
                                    useGoogleFonts: false,
                                    lineHeight: 1.5,
                                  ),
                              contextMenuBuilder: (context, editableTextState) {
                                final TextEditingValue value = editableTextState.textEditingValue;
                                final List<ContextMenuButtonItem> buttonItems =
                                    editableTextState.contextMenuButtonItems;
                                final textoSeleccionado = value.selection.textInside(value.text);
                                if (isSeleccionado(value.selection.textInside(value.text))) {
                                  buttonItems.insert(
                                      0,
                                      ContextMenuButtonItem(
                                        label: 'Cambiar a Rojo',                                        
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          ///ContextMenuController.removeAny();                                          
                                          ///Navigator.of(context).push(_showDialog(context, textoSeleccionado));                                          
                                           setState(() {
                                              SelectableText(
                                              textoSeleccionado,
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                  .bodyMedium
                                                  .override(
                                                    fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
                                                    color: Colors.redAccent,
                                                    letterSpacing: 2.0,
                                                    useGoogleFonts: false,
                                                    lineHeight: 1.5,
                                                  ),
                                            );
                                           });                                                                                                                            
                                        },                                        
                                      )
                                    );
                                }
                                return AdaptiveTextSelectionToolbar.buttonItems(
                                  anchors: editableTextState.contextMenuAnchors,
                                  buttonItems: buttonItems,
                                );
                              },                              
                            )
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
bool isSeleccionado(String text) {
  return true;
}
```

Cualquier sugerencia se les agradece, ya que soy bastante novato con flutter.
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar, primero crearás una lista booleana que será de la misma cantidad de elementos que tiene tu lista actual:

```
final List<bool> _selected = List.generate(listViewPredicasRecordList.length, (i) => false);
```

Esto nos servirá para poder establecer el color por item de lista, ya que el color que estás dando actualmente es para toda la lista. Para hacerlo mas sencillo y no tan extenso no use `FlutterFlowTheme` simplemente use `TextStyle` por defecto, ahora lo que haras es reemplazar `color`, esta variable `color` será una variable de clase:

```
Color color = Colors.black;
```

ahora en la propiedad `color` de `FlutterFlowTheme` solo tendras que realizar una pequeña validación para que el color cambie dependiendo del index en el que se encuentre(el index ya lo proporciona el `ListView`). Y ahora solo editamos un poco el `SelectableText` la parte del `style`:

```
 //Reemplaza esto
    style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
           .bodyMedium
           .override(
             fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
             color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).black600,
             letterSpacing: 2.0,
             useGoogleFonts: false,
             lineHeight: 1.5,
    )

   // Por esto:
      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
           .bodyMedium
           .override(
             fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
             //El color por defecto siempre va a ser negro
             color: _selected[index] ? color : null
             letterSpacing: 2.0,
             useGoogleFonts: false,
             lineHeight: 1.5,
    )
```

Y ya únicamente en el `onPressed` le harémos un `setState` al item de la lista de booleanos para actualizar su estado a True y actualizaremos el color a rojo:

```
onPressed: () {                                          
 setState(() {
      /*Esto no sirve, elimina esto y usa el código que esta debajo
      SelectableText(
      textoSeleccionado,
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
      style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
             .bodyMedium
             .override(
                fontFamily: 'Droid Serif',
                color: Colors.redAccent,
                letterSpacing: 2.0,
                useGoogleFonts: false,
                lineHeight: 1.5,
             ),
            );*/

            //Con esto ya debería funcionar tu código
               _selected[index] = true;
               color = Colors.red;
          });
         }
```

Espero mi respuesta te haya servido.